# I want to Install FOSUser Bundle in Symfony but geting Composer error

Tags: php, composer-php, fosuserbundle, symfony-3.2

I want to Install FOSUser Bundle in Symfony but geting Composer error, **'composer' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file**. I have also attached screen shot. I did many R&D about this topic but unable to install.

[enter image description here][1]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZrHp.jpg)

In my second screenshot I am showing step which I following for install FOSUser Bundle.

I have attached updated error Screenshot
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aont4.jpg)

Comment: have you installed composer? https://getcomposer.org/ It doesn't look like it

Comment: if there is a composer phar you can run the same composer commands by typing `php composer.phar require whoever/package`

Comment: Sir I Downloaded and run Composer-Setup.exe - it will install the latest composer version whenever it is executed.  But After this I am facing Same issue I run this command "composer require friendsofsymfony/user-bundle "~1.3"".

Comment: once composer is installed, you should be able to type `composer` from any directory in your command line and you'll see a bunch of options

Comment: Sorry Sir but unable to work. 
"C:\xampp\htdocs\FOSUserTry>composer

'composer' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

Comment: where did it install to?

Comment: When I installed composer my first step was. C:\xampp\php\php.exe

Comment: "Composer (version 1.5.2) successfully installed to: C:\xampp\htdocs\FOSUserTry\bin\composer.phar
Use it: php bin/composer.phar"  Sir can you tell me whether I am going right or wrong

Comment: `php bin/composer.phar init` then `php bin/composer.phar require whoever/package`

Comment: Sir through php composer.phar I have seen "Composer version 1.5.2 2017-09-11 16:59:25" and Many Available commands: about,archive etc

Comment: run those two commands ^^ obviously replacing whoever with friends of symfony package

Comment: Through "php composer.phar require friendsofsymfony/user-bundle "~2.0""  command I  "Download FOSUserBundle using composer" but this time I am facing this error at the time of update my schema "PHP Fatal error:  Class 'FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\FOSUserTry\src\AppBundle\Entity\User.php on line 13" Sir can you suggest me. thanks in advance

Comment: you need composers autoloader. `require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';` right at the start of your script

Comment: Sorry Sir for inconvenience but I am unable to understand means in which script i should require_once this text. I have attached error screen shot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through "php composer.phar require friendsofsymfony/user-bundle "~2.0"" command I "Download FOSUserBundle using composer"

Comment: Finally I created my FOSUser Bundle in Symfony 3. Thanks all.